# How to wrap a resizable div around a image using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Im trying to wrap a div around a image both when the width or height changes.

The issue is that when the width changes the div does not tightly wrap against the child in this case the child is a image:

[Wrap div around a image current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TsXJ.gif)

I did determine that setting the flex-direction between row and column solves it when the div gets resized and could use something like a resize observer to toggle the flex direction but hope there is a css solution to this?

Here is a code pen with the issue: https://codepen.io/quinnaz/pen/rNJdjJy

```
<div class="container direction-row">
  <div class="border">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x600/d4b9d4/7477a3.png" class="img-element" />
  </div>
</div>

.container {
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: beige;
  border: solid;
  display: flex;
}

.direction-row {
  flex-direction: row;
}
.direction-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.img-element {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.border {
  border-width: 50px;
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: if the image and the div have different aspect-ratios the image will not fit by default. SO an `object-fit` rule has to be set to the image to specifcy that an image either should be streched or cropped to fit the div.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `object-fit` property and give it the value `cover`. I would also change `max-width` and `max-height` to `width` and `height` respectively.

The replaced content (in this case an image) is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element's entire content box. If the object's aspect ratio does not match the aspect ratio of its box, then the object will be clipped to fit.

**codepen link**  https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/ZErxevo

```
.img-element {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

** **EDIT** **

If you want it to fully fit the `.container` div you'll then need to make the `.border` div fill the parent `.container` with `width: 100%;` `height: 100%;` set on `.border`, this isn't clear in the question though. If not the above snippet should do the trick.

Personally I would just add the border to the image and remove the extra div and CSS.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer, unfortunatley I don't think my question is clear enough. I wanted the div to shrink-wrap around the image when it gets resized keeping its aspect ratio. Did try the solutions you presented but no luck so far.

Comment: @Quinnaz - do you mean you want it like this in the amended codepen link: https://codepen.io/thechewy/pen/ZErxevo if so I'll amend the answer.